# How can I replace some calls to JavaScript's eval() with Ext.decode()?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, eval

We are trying to get rid of all of our `eval()` calls in our JavaScript.  Unfortunately, I am not much of a JavaScript programmer, and I need some help.

Many of our `eval()` calls operate on strings, outputs from a web service, that are very JSON-like, for example, we might eval the following string:

```
ClassMetaData['Asset$Flex'] = {
  fields: {
    }
  ,label: 'Flex Fields'
};
```

I've seen various suggestions on the Internet suggesting `Ext.decode()`.  The [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.JSON.html#method-decode) for it says - "Decodes (parses) a JSON string to an object. If the JSON is invalid, this function throws a SyntaxError unless the safe option is set."  The string that I am supplying as an argument isn't legitimate JSON as I understand it (the field names aren't quoted), but `Ext.decode()` nearly works for me anyway.  If I decode the above string, I get an error (why?) - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;".  However, if I remove the trailing semi-colon, and decode, everything seems to be fine.

I am using the following code to determine whether the `decode` call and the `eval` call do the same thing:

```
var evaled = eval(inputString);
var decoded = Ext.decode(inputString.replace(";", "")); // remove trailing ";", if any
console.log("Equal? - " + (JSON.stringify(decoded) == JSON.stringify(evaled)));
```

Unfortunately, this is not a very good solution.  For example, some of the input strings to `eval` are fairly complex.  They may have all sorts of embedded characters - semicolons, HTML character encodings, etc.  `Decode` may complain about some other syntax problem, besides semicolons at the end, and I haven't found a good way to determine where the problem is that decode objects to.  (It doesn't say "illegal character in position 67", for example.)

My questions:

1. Could we, with a small amount of work, create a generic solution
   using `decode`?
2. Is there an easy way to convert our JSON-like input
   into true JSON?
3. Is there a better way of comparing the results of
   `eval` and `decode` than `JSON.stringify(decoded) ==    JSON.stringify(evaled)`?

Comment: So you can't touch the code that is making the invalid JSON?

Comment: @epascarello - If necessary, we can modify the web service code.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how that might affect other consumers of the web services.  Also, it would likely be more work than we'd prefer.

Comment: So than add a different output mode `?output=json` :) There is really not much you can do to deal with invalid JSON. It is `eval()` or `new Function(){}`

Comment: It is probably possible to write a regexp to turn `"ClassMetaData['Asset$Flex'] = {fields: {},label: 'Flex Fields'};"` into valid JSON eg. `'{"data":{"fields":{},"label":"Flex Fields"},"namespace":"Asset$Flex","type": "ClassMetaData"}'`, but that would also need a rewrite of alot of the engine handling the original no-JSON strings. Also: +1 for this marvellous example of the inner platform effect.

Comment: Try using JSON.parse(inputString) nested inside a try catch block to handle exceptions